# What permissions are needed to read /write external collaboration policies?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I've written a powershell script that allows me to query azure for my azure ad policies like this:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$currentpolicy = Get-AzureADPolicy -All $true | ?{$_.Type -eq 'B2BManagementPolicy'} | select -First 1
$currentpolicy
$newPolicyValue = @("{`"B2BManagementPolicy`":{`"InvitationsAllowedAndBlockedDomainsPolicy`":{`"AllowedDomains`": [`"a.com`",`"b.org`",`"c.org`",`"d.com`"],`"BlockedDomains`": []}}}")
```

}
#update existing.  This works.  tested.
Set-AzureADPolicy -Definition $newPolicyValue -Id $currentpolicy.Id

This works because I'm signing in with an account that's got "owner" / global admin permissions. Now we wnat to try to figure out the specific permissions that are needed and just assign those to a new AD app registration.

I've created a service principal with a cert, and I changed my code like this:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tid -ApplicationId $appid -CertificateThumbprint $thumb
$currentpolicy = Get-AzureADPolicy -All $true | ?{$_.Type -eq 'B2BManagementPolicy'} | select -First 1
$currentpolicy
```

I didn't add any specific permissions yet, and so when I run my script, I see the following error:

```
Get-AzureADPolicy : Error occurred while executing GetPolicies
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
InnerError:
  RequestId: d88cd5d5-f8c9-4a4d-928b-986e0d5c25eb
  DateTimeStamp: Thu, 16 Jun 2022 19:06:45 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Users\me\Documents\src\test\setPolicy.ps1:4 char:18
+ $currentpolicy = Get-AzureADPolicy -All $true | ?{$_.Type -eq 'B2BMan ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADPolicy], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.GetPolicy
```

Ideally, we want to use MS Graph permissions to do this.  So i've been poking around in Azure, under the "API Permissions" for this application registration, but so far I haven't figured out which permission I need to add.

PS I know that the AzureADPreview and AzureAD is going away.  But so far, it's the only way that I can automate these tasks. I have another stack question open about how to get this entire thing working via Graph

**EDIT 1**

I've tried the following permissions and none of them work so far...

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I've granted Policy.Read.All and now I can read the policies.  Now it fails trying to update the existing policy.

It'd be nice to know specificially which read permission is needed so I don't have to grant all.

As far as write permissions, I've granted everything that comes up when I search for "policy" but none of them allow me to write!

**EDIT 3**

I've added the policy.readwrite.applicationconfiguration but that doesn't allow me to write.  I'm still get the insufficient privleges error when I try to call Set-AzureADPolicy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found an answer, but as this is one of the first results that came up, I will add my findings.

I could get nowhere from giving specific permissions to the Service Principal but adding the **Security Administrator role** to the app did the trick. I didn't want to give the service principal so much access, but I tried a lot of roles and permission combinations, and none were sufficient.

Apparently, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task#external-identitiesb2c) states that the least privileged role that is able to configure B2B external collaboration settings is the [Global Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USBuJ.png). Although for this case specifically, of changing the B2BManagementPolicy via PowerShell with a service principal, the Security Administration role was enough in my testing.

Looking at the actions that this role can perform I suspect it's because it has access to microsoft.directory/policies/basic/update, but I can't be sure.

Note: When adding a role to an App registration in Azure AD you need to search for its name when selecting the members, as they don't show by default.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for reaching out , with the help you read access , you will only able to get the data ,if you want to add or update you should have write permission as well , please add permission Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration and try again .
[image]

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tenantappmanagementpolicy-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

**Edit 2**

Update policy is available for PowerShell 2.0 preview [image]

To update you need to use
Set-AzureADPolicy -ObjectId  -DisplayName

To learn more about Set-AzureADPolicy, please checkout - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview&viewFallbackFrom=azureadps-2.0

Thanks

Comment: thank you but that doesn't seem to address the problem.  Please see Edit 3.  I've added the permission you suggest for my app registration.  But it still fails.

Comment: thanks for the update , please check my updated answer (edit 2)

Comment: hi there.  so I already know about Set-AzureADPolicy.(I mentioned that in Edit 3)  that's what I'm using to try to change the policy.  Sorry.  Maybe my edit 3 wasn't clear.  But the issue isn't that I don't know what function to use, it's the fact that the permissions don't allow me to do it.  I'll update my post to show you the code after the Get-AzureADPolicy.,